# Unable to tap an on-screen button in Safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

As shown in the screenshot, I am unable to tap the Done button in Safari on my iPhone. When I attempt to tap it, the tap isn't registered and the Safari toolbar is displayed instead.

[image]

I can't scroll the webpage to move the back button upwards.

Comment: *Which* button?

Comment: The "Done" button. Also edited question.

Comment: Does this happen to all web pages or just the specific one in the images?  If it's just one site, the problem is probably bad coding on the web page and not the device.

Comment: Just this one, but I can imagine similar sizing issues